# How can I allow cross domain in node js web application?

Tags: php, node.js

I have built a webchat application in Node.js and a CMS in PHP.

Now I want to use WEBCHAT in CMS through an `<iframe>`. Both are on the same domain with a different port. But I cannot access webchat's `<iframe>` (NODE JS) in CMS (PHP).

Comment: I have already explained what is my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link can shed some light if you use Expressjs with Node: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Here is a quick example.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // Handle the post for this route
});
```

There are a lot of resources about enabling CORS inside Node (even without express js) and inside PHP